# Chapter in memoir not displaying correctly in TOC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, memoir, chapters

I'm having a little problem with a custom chapter style in memoir class. I want to have the chapter titles behaving like parts, i.e. having the title on a separate page.

I can do it like so:

```
\makechapterstyle{emmanuel}{%
\chapterstyle{ger}
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\cleardoublepage}
}
```

Trouble is, in the toc, the page number displayed for the chapter is the one for the next page. I take it that this is due to the chapter actually starting right before page (n+2), but I would like to have it starting on the page title (i.e. n)

I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the internal `\@chapter` command to include the `\cleardoublepage` command at the appropriate location (if you do it too early, the wrong page number will be picked for the ToC):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand\chapterclear{
\gdef\@chapter[##1]##2{%
  \m@mpn@new@chaptrue%
  \m@mpn@new@schapfalse%
  \def\f@rbdy{##2}%
  \ifx\ch@pt@c\@empty % no optional args
    \def\f@rtoc{##2}%
    \def\f@rhdr{##2}%
  \else                  % at least one opt arg
    \let\f@rtoc\ch@pt@c
    \ifx\@empty##1\@empty
      \let\f@rhdr\ch@pt@c
    \else
      \def\f@rhdr{##1}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \m@m@Andfalse
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
      \m@m@Andtrue
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifm@m@And
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \fi
  \ifartopt
    \@makechapterhead{##2}%
    \@afterheading
    \chaptermark{\f@rhdr}%
  \else
    \chaptermark{\f@rhdr}
    \insertchapterspace
    \if@twocolumn
      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{##2}]%
    \else
      \@makechapterhead{##2}%
    \fi
    \@afterheading
  \fi
  \ifm@m@And
    \ifanappendix
      \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}{%
        \protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}%
      \memappchapinfo{\thechapter}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{##2}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
        \protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}%
      \memchapinfo{\thechapter}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{##2}%
    \fi
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\f@rtoc}%
    \ifanappendix
      \memappchapinfo{}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{##2}%
    \else
      \memchapinfo{}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{##2}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifheadnameref\M@gettitle{\f@rhdr}\else\M@gettitle{\f@rtoc}\fi
  \cleardoublepage}%
}
\makeatother

\makechapterstyle{emmanuel}{
  \chapterstyle{ger}
  \chapterclear
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapterstyle{emmanuel}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```